# Imagick compareImages on 2 different images gives only result of 0.21

Tags: php, imagick

I have compared 2 images filled with different colors [gray.jpg](http://test.parkes.org.ua/m_parser/gray.jpg) and [red.jpg](http://test.parkes.org.ua/m_parser/red.jpg). Both 500x500. Result gives me difference - 0.21. Why so low? I expected result - 1(completely different images). Images above - for test. I need to compare jpg images with different dimentions.

```
$image1 = new imagick();
$image2 = new imagick();     

$image1->readImage("gray.jpg");
$image2->readImage("red.jpg");   

$result = $image2->compareImages($image1, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR); 
var_dump($result[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This metric is measuring the mathematical differences using [Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).

> I expected result - 1(completely different images).

Not really. The only way to achieve 1 is if your comparing a solid black image (zero value: 0) to a solid white image (quantum value: 2<sup>16</sup>). The MSE metric is not a truthful boolean, but more of an estimate of how far apart two images are.

> 0.21. Why so low?

Perhaps the best way to answer this question is a quick walkthrough of the maths involved. I'll be ignoring quantum values (sticking to 0...255 range), and rounding considerably. Luckily both images supplied are solid colors, so we only have to calculate this on the first pixel.

Given two pixels...

```
     | R   | G   | B   |
     +-----+-----+-----+
red  | 182 |   0 |   1 | 
     +-----+-----+-----+
gray | 142 | 142 | 142 |
```

Find the distance between each channel

```
     | R   | G   | B   |
     +-----+-----+-----+
dist |  40 | 142 | 141 |
```

Convert to double and scale between 0.0 and 1.0

```
double | 0.156 | 0.556 | 0.552
```

Square

```
square | 0.024 | 0.309 | 0.305
```

Finally find the average across all color channels

```
avg | 0.211 |
```

Again, you would to the last step for all color channels across all pixels.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Got it, thank you. How can I get difference between images in percentage?

Comment: I need to detect duplicate images.

Comment: Pictures are equal, but size differs